# Backbone.js: add product twice to cart with new attributes. Correct MV architecture?

Tags: backbone.js, model, shopping-cart

I'm building an app that gets a collection of products from a JSON file and stores these as models in a collection.  The user can:

1. select multiple instances of a product
2. customise them - change colours, change materials, etc.

I don't have these attributes on the product model at the moment.

How would I go about setting this up?  Would I add all the possible customisation attributes to the original model?  I'm assuming I'd probably need a **Cart Collection**?  Would I need a separate **Cart Item Model** that is cloned from the original **Product Model**?  and would the best place to set all this up be in the main **App View**?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've just started with backbone and have a lot to learn!

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested model to wrapper Product Model as a attribute of Cart Item Model.

And when customise product by set deferent colours or size, if the API RETURN DEFERENT ID for deferent size or colour, you may be create new instance for each of them.